# Correct CSS media query to serve iPhone <= 3 and iPhone 4+ different images (without wasting bandwidth)

Tags: iphone, html, performance, css

After reading this excellent article on Media Queries (http://www.cloudfour.com/css-media-query-for-mobile-is-fools-gold/). I want to be sure that my media queries for an (iphone only) webapp are correct and the users' iphones will not download the unneccessary background images intended for a different iPhone device.

is this correct?

```
/* IPHONE 3 IMAGES
================================*/
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
    /* my small background imgs here.... */    
}

/* IPHONE 4 'retina' IMAGES
================================*/
@media all and (max-device-width: 480px){
    /* my high-res background imgs here.... */    
}
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the image, you could just combine the image into a sprite to prevent the double download and double http request overhead. Or just feed the large image to all phones and resize it using background-size.

Answer (score 1):

You could use @media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) to target pre-iphone 4, but this will only work if the browser knows about min-devive-pixel-ratio. So older iPhone versions and other browsers will load neither rules. The only way to do this is either serverside (not sure if it is possible to differentiate between iphone 4 and iOS 4), or use JS to detect and load either of the 2 rules.

Both not ideal so I would personally opt for just accepting the extra download. Maybe even sending the large image to both, because http overhead is far worse than a few extra bytes of body, but this depends on the image size.